# Node.JS Get data from Http Request POST

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, httprequest

I am new to Node.js and am writing a AWS Lambda function in Node.js to get data from a REST endpoint and sending the data back to Alexa. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
  var req = http.request(post_options, function(response) {
      var str = '';

      response.setEncoding('utf8');

      //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
      response.on('data', function(chunk) {
          str += chunk;
      });

      //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
      response.on('end', function() {

          var result = JSON.parse(str);

          text = 'According to Weather Underground, the temperature in ' + citySlot + ',' + stateSlot + ' feels like ';
          text += result.HighFahr0 + " degrees fahrenheit.";

          console.log("text::"+text);
      });
  });

  req.write(post_data);
  //this.emit(':ask', text, "Anything else i can help you with?");
  req.end();
```

If i execute this.emit right after building the text string, it does not work. If i execute this.emit after the req.write function, the text variable is out of scope and contains nothing. How do i get the contents of the text variable after req.write() and req.end()?

Thanks Very Much.

Answer (score 0):

Declare text before the request. I hope it should work then.

```
var text;
var req = http.request(post_options, function(response) {
      var str = '';

      response.setEncoding('utf8');

      //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
      response.on('data', function(chunk) {
          str += chunk;
      });

      //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
      response.on('end', function() {

          var result = JSON.parse(str);

          text = 'According to Weather Underground, the temperature in ' + citySlot + ',' + stateSlot + ' feels like ';
          text += result.HighFahr0 + " degrees fahrenheit.";

          console.log("text::"+text);
      });
  });

  req.write(post_data);
  this.emit(':ask', text, "Anything else i can help you with?");
  req.end();
```

Comment: this did not work. I initialized as var text = ' '; when the text got printed at the end, it was printed as blank...

Comment: Try writting last three lines in the response.on('end') block